# list enabled systemd service instances

Tags: service, systemd, multiple-instances

I'd like to list all enabled service instances.

The following lists enabled services, but only shows the service, and not individual instance:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```

The following lists all running instances:

```
systemctl list-units --state=running
```

I would expect something like the following to show enabled instances:

```
systemctl list-units --state=enabled
```

But that does not work.

So, if I start two service instances with:

```
systemctl start foo-service@primary
systemctl start foo-service@secondary
```

...but then I only enable one:

```
systemctl enable foo-service@secondary
```

The only way I've been able to find out which instances are enabled is with:

```
ls /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
```

But that seems very kludge-y.  Is there a systemd way of doing this?  Version is 237 if it matters.

Comment: This question is more or less identical to [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/963456/20001) on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for `systemctl list-units --state=loaded`.

Comment: That seems to come back with false positives.  For example, using that method I am seeing a service in `loaded failed failed` state for a unit where `is-enabled` comes back as `static`.